# Not able to use Stratified-K-Fold on multi label classifier

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning, cross-validation

The following code is used to do KFold Validation but I am to train the model as it is throwing the error

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_14 to have shape (7,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

My target Variable has 7 classes. I am using `LabelEncoder` to encode the classes into numbers.

By seeing this error, If I am changing the into `MultiLabelBinarizer` to encode the classes. I am getting the following error

```
ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'multilabel-indicator' instead.
```

The following is the code for KFold validation

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)
scores = np.zeros(10)
idx = 0
for index, (train_indices, val_indices) in enumerate(skf.split(X, y)):
    print("Training on fold " + str(index+1) + "/10...")
    # Generate batches from indices
    xtrain, xval = X[train_indices], X[val_indices]
    ytrain, yval = y[train_indices], y[val_indices]
    model = None
    model = load_model() //defined above

    scores[idx] = train_model(model, xtrain, ytrain, xval, yval)
    idx+=1
print(scores)
print(scores.mean())
```

I don't know what to do. I want to use Stratified K Fold on my model. Please help me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`MultiLabelBinarizer` returns a vector which is of the length of your number of classes.

If you look at how `StratifiedKFold` [splits](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.split) your dataset, you will see that it only accepts a one-dimensional target variable, whereas you are trying to pass a target variable with dimensions `[n_samples, n_classes]`

Stratefied split basically preserves your class distribution. And if you think about it, it does not make a lot of sense if you have a multi-label classification problem.

If you want to preserve the distribution in terms of the different combinations of classes in your target variable, then the answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65828/how-to-use-scikit-learns-cross-validation-functions-on-multi-label-classifiers) explains two ways in which you can define your own stratefied split function.

### UPDATE:

The logic is something like this:

Assuming you have `n` classes and your target variable is a combination of these `n` classes. You will have `(2^n) - 1` combinations (Not including all 0s). You can now create a new target variable considering each combination as a new label.

For example, if `n=3`, you will have `7` unique combinations:

```
 1. [1, 0, 0]
 2. [0, 1, 0]
 3. [0, 0, 1]
 4. [1, 1, 0]
 5. [1, 0, 1]
 6. [0, 1, 1]
 7. [1, 1, 1]
```

Map all your labels to this new target variable. You can now look at your problem as simple **multi-class** classification, instead of **multi-label** classification.

Now you can directly use `StartefiedKFold` using `y_new` as your target. Once the splits are done, you can map your labels back.

Code sample:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
y = np.random.randint(0, 2, (10, 7))
y = y[np.where(y.sum(axis=1) != 0)[0]]
```

OUTPUT:

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Label encode your class vectors:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

def get_new_labels(y):
    y_new = LabelEncoder().fit_transform([''.join(str(l)) for l in y])
    return y_new

y_new = get_new_labels(y)
```

OUTPUT:

```
array([7, 6, 3, 3, 2, 5, 8, 0, 4, 1])
```

Comment: I am not able to understand the solution given in the link. It was so complicated. Can you explain to me how to use that function in my problem?

Comment: @SaiPavan Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I code you shared is working. But I don't seem to understand the logic behind it.

Comment: @SaiPavan which part exactly? I'd suggest you read about how stratefied splits work and why `sklearn` does not support it for multi-label problems. The main idea here is to transform your problem into a multi-class one so you can apply stratefied splits.

Comment: I don't understand that by directly using label encoder doesn't work but using fit_transform in between works

Comment: @SaiPavan Sorry I don't quite understand what you mean by "using label encoder doesn't work". You **always** have to use `fit_transform` with `LabelEncoder` whenever you want to transform your labels.

Comment: That's where I got it wrong. If you see my question, I have applied `LabelEncoder` to my class variable but I was still getting the error 1 because I didn't apply `fit_transform` then.

Comment: @SaiPavan You have not included your code for label encoding. So I can't say what went wrong there.

Comment: @panktijk thanks for your answer. It seems to me that the `''.join()` you use is not necessary, right? Did you have any reason to use that instead of just calling `str(l)`?

Comment: I believe the `''.join(str(l))` part is only done to create a unique representation of each combination. You could use any function that returns a string I think as long as it makes a unique combination for the labelencoder to encode

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on the great work of @panktijk work, here is a full example. Perhaps this could be merged into his answer?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedGroupKFold, StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder


np.random.seed(1)
N = 1000
X = np.random.random((N, 100))
y = np.random.randint(0, 2, (N, 7))


def get_new_labels(y):
    """ Convert each multilabel vector to a unique string """
    yy = [''.join(str(l)) for l in y]
    y_new = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(yy)
    return y_new

y_new = get_new_labels(y)
folder = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2)

for train_indices, test_indices in folder.split(X, y_new):
    # Do stuff with train and test indices
```

Answer (score 0):

With the Github project 'iterative-stratification' with `MultilabelStratifiedKFold()` [...] there also exists a `scikit-learn` compatible implementation:

https://github.com/trent-b/iterative-stratification