# Stratifying folds with StratifiedKFold in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn

I do not understand very well the logic behind `sklearn` function `train_test_split` and `StratifiedKFold` for obtaining balanced splits according to multiple "columns" and not only according to the target distribution. I know the previous sentence is a bit obscure so I hope the following code helps.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

n_samples = 100
prob = 0.2
pos = int(n_samples * prob)
neg = n_samples - pos

target = [1] * pos + [0] * neg
cat = ["a"] * 50 + ["b"] * 50
random.shuffle(target)
random.shuffle(cat)

ds = pd.DataFrame()
ds["target"] = target
ds["cat"] = cat
ds["f1"] = np.random.random(size=(n_samples,))
ds["f2"] = np.random.random(size=(n_samples,))
print(ds.head())
```

This is a 100-example dataset, target distribution is governed by `p`, in this case we have 20% positive examples. There is a binary categorical column `cat`, perfectly balanced. The output of the previous code is:

```
     target cat        f1        f2
0       0   a  0.970585  0.134268
1       0   a  0.410689  0.225524
2       0   a  0.638111  0.273830
3       0   b  0.594726  0.579668
4       0   a  0.737440  0.667996
```

with `train_test_split()`, `stratify` on `target` and `cat`, if we study the frequencies, we get:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, StratifiedKFold

# with train_test_split
training, valid = train_test_split(range(n_samples), 
                test_size=20, 
                stratify=ds[["target", "cat"]])

print("---")
print("* training")
print(ds.loc[training, ["target", "cat"]].value_counts() / len(training))  # balanced
print("* validation")
print(ds.loc[valid, ["target", "cat"]].value_counts() / len(valid))  # balanced
```

we get this:

```
* dataset
0    0.8
1    0.2
Name: target, dtype: float64
target  cat
0       a      0.4
        b      0.4
1       a      0.1
        b      0.1
dtype: float64
---
* training
target  cat
0       a      0.4
        b      0.4
1       a      0.1
        b      0.1
dtype: float64
* validation
target  cat
0       a      0.4
        b      0.4
1       a      0.1
        b      0.1
dtype: float64
```

It is perfectly stratified.

Now with `StratifiedKFold`:

```
# with stratified k-fold
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)
try:
    for train, valid in skf.split(X=range(len(ds)), y=ds[["target", "cat"]]):
        pass
except:
    print("! does not work")


for train, valid in skf.split(X=range(len(ds)), y=ds.target):
    print("happily iterating")
```

output:

```
! does not work
happily iterating
happily iterating
happily iterating
happily iterating
happily iterating
```

How do I obtain what I got with `train_test_split` with `StratifiedKFold`? I know there might be data distributions not allowing such stratifications in k-fold cross validation, but I cannot understand why `train_test_split` accepts two or more columns and the other method does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem readily possible currently.

Multilabel isn't exactly what you're looking for, but related.  That's been [asked here before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54890899/10495893), and was an [Issue on sklearn's github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/11795) (not sure why it got closed).

As a bit of a hack, you should be able to just combine your two columns into a new one with ordered pairs, and stratify on that?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The combination of the columns in a new one was the solution I adopted, but I was hoping my understanding of `StratifiedKFold` was wrong.